SFTP error - " Remote side sent SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO not either preceded by NEWKEYS or followed by USERAUTH_SUCCESS"
Hi I'm getting below error when tried to connect to SFTP site via Filezilla/WinSCP.
Although it works meaning able to connect to site sometime but sometime it won't connect.
Can any one please advise?
Getting error - "Remote side sent SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO not either preceded by NEWKEYS or followed by USERAUTH_SUCCESS"
Using SSH private key authentication method - not using any passpharse for login.
SSH PrivateKey format as per below
----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY------ 
....
....
-----END RSA pRIVATE KEY-----


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

According to https://openssh-unix-dev.mindrot.narkive.com/Injs07lQ/why-ssh-client-breaks-connection-in-expecting-ssh2-msg-newkeys-state, there may be a dialog requesting confirmation to proceed that has been ignored. Do you have access to remote site?

Hi @DrMoishePippik - Yes I did Click YES on "Always Trust this host abd carry on connecting" - Pop up.
No don't have access to remote host.
Although it connect sometime but sometime it not connect.

BTW, one oddball SSH/SFTP issue I've seen is when time on two machines is out of sync. Key exchange includes a time component, so they cannot simply be recorded and reused. Might have nothing to do with your issue, though.

I don;t think so any issue in Timezone as well as time and date

The information you've added as comments here and as replies to the answer below should also be added to your question to help fill it out and make it more clear and complete. The better and more complete your question is, the more likely it is someone with the right answer will be able to find it, and give you a good answer.

You need to check a few things.
It could be something with the SSH client, the private key setup, network issues, or even server configuration.
What SSH client and version are you using? Are you authenticating with an SSH private key? and if so, what key type and format?
Is the key passphrase-protected, and if so, is it being handled correctly?
Have you checked the SSH server logs?
Do you know the version of the SSH server, and have there been any recent configuration changes?
Is the issue consistent or intermittent?
If intermittent, does it happen under specific conditions or at certain times?
Are you experiencing any network issues such as packet loss, high latency, or connectivity problems? Is there any firewall or security software, either on the client or server side, that could be interfering with the SSH connection?
Have you tried connecting from a different machine or network to see if the problem persists?
Have there been any recent updates or changes to the system (either client or server) that could be impacting SSH connectivity?

Hi @Kiyomizu
Using SSH private key authentication method - not using any passpharse for login
SSH PrivateKey format as per below
----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY------
....
-----END RSA pRIVATE KEY----
What SSH client and version are you using?- OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.5p1, LibreSSL 3.8.2
Connection to SFTP site is not consistent meaning it connect sometime and sometime it failed with above error.
Tried on another windows machine same issue even started with fresh.

in that case, Is your private key in the correct PEM format ? Have you checked that it's valid and matches the public key on the server? You can verify it using ssh-keygen -l -f private_key_file.
Have there been any recent changes to the server configuration, like stricter key requirements or updates that might affect compatibility?
Are you able to enable debug logging on your SSH client / run a command like sftp -vvv -i private_key_file user@hostname? What error message do you see?
Does the server support RSA keys, or is it set up to only accept newer key types like ED25519 or ECDSA?

okay,   Are the permissions on your private key and the server’s authorized_keys file set correctly?

Also, Is your SSH client using the right private key?
Add -vvv.

Debug result.
Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
Failed to open file:C:/Users/onepl/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
load_hostkeys: fopen C:\Users\onepl/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
load_hostkeys: fopen PROGRAMDATA\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
ssh_get_authentication_socket_path: path '\\.\pipe\openssh-ssh-agent'
unable to connect to pipe \\.\pipe\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
but it is connected

yes permission is correct. Both Public and Private SSH key same comared using sh-keygen -l -f private_key_file
Connected via Command line but on/off via filezilla/winscp

Please advise how to check -Does the server support RSA keys, or is it set up to only accept newer key types like ED25519 or ECDSA?

To check if a server supports RSA keys, here’s what I usually do:
Use SSH Debugging: Run ssh -vv user@server to see which key types the server accepts during the connection process.
Test Specific Keys: Try connecting with specific keys like RSA (ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@server) or ED25519 to see what works.
Check Key Algorithms: Run ssh -Q key on your client to see what it supports and compare with the server.

Additionally, Fetch Server Host Keys: Use ssh-keyscan -t rsa,ecdsa,ed25519 server to see what the server is configured to use.
Check Server Config: If you have admin access, look at /etc/ssh/sshd_config for key type settings like PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes.

I can  see both Server and Client are supporting KEX algorithm ran above command (ssh -vv and ssh -vv -i)

when I run ssh-keyscan -t rsa,ecdsa,ed25519 server. I see ssh-rsa somebig text like AAAAF90.....
Still wondering why it works sometimes and sometimes it failed while connecting thrugh Filezilla and WinScp.
Works when I run comand sftp -i private_key user@server also works on MobaXterm.
Please help me to correct  this issue. Really appreciate your advise.
